# facing trouble to get the screen shot from the UIWebview when playing the video

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, uiimageview

I am facing trouble to get the screen shot from the UIWebview when playing the video.

I am using the below code to play the video in UIWebView:

```
webViewHere.delegate=self;
webViewHere.scrollView.bounces = NO;
webViewHere.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webViewHere.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
NSURL *websiteUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.testapp.com/youtube21.html?videoid=wWWhOEtUBt4&st=7&en=27&height=270&auto=1&ctrl=0&p2p=1"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
[webViewHere loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

I am using the below code to take the screen shot:

```
CGRect rect = [webViewHere bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[webViewHere.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *imageHere = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
screenShotImageView.image=imageHere;
```

I tried like this also.. same code but small change:

```
 CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 240);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
 [webViewHere.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 screenShotImage= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 screenShotImageView.image=imageHere;
```

Please find the attached images,
the screenshot appears when the video stops or when the video loading time.
But when the video is playing it returns black screen.
[image]

Please guide me, Thank in Advance

Comment: have you tried on device?  and is this youtube video?

Comment: can you give us video url to check/

Comment: yes.. i checked in the device also same problem occurs.... can u please check now.. i edited the url in my code... @Virussmca

Comment: In my webview even video is is not loaded, its only see blank screen :(

Comment: When i play it using youtube link it is playing but in fullscreen not only in webview,

Comment: can u please check now.. i added few more lines .. @Virussmca

Comment: is it working now without full screen playing? @Virussmca

Comment: I have tested it in <iframe> and it will play in fullscreen

Comment: `NSString *embedHTML = @"<iframe width=\"200\" height=\"200\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/wWWhOEtUBt4\" ></iframe>";    [self.webViewHere loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];` like this.

Comment: I am putting what i have done in answer, in comment it will not looks propser so..

Comment: Sorry i am testing it on **ios6** version and it not playing.

Comment: check this may be it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573345/how-can-i-programmatically-capture-a-screenshot-of-a-playing-video

Comment: @Babul did u find a solution for this  ???

Comment: Still looking for a solution as well...