# Screenshot for AVPlayer and Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to take a screenshot of an `AVPlayer` inside a bigger view. I want to build a testing framework only, so private `APIs` or any method is good, because the framework will not be included when releasing to the AppStore.

I have tried with using

- `UIGetScreenImage()` : works well on simulator but not on device
- `snapshotviewafterscreenupdates`: it shows the view but I cannot create a `UIImage` from that.
- `drawViewInHierarchy` and `renderInContext` will not work with `AVPlayer`
- I don't want to use `AVAssetGenerator` for getting image from video, it is hard to get a good coordinate or the video player as the subview of other views

Comment: If renderInContext doesn't work directly, could you first do snapshotviewafterscreenupdates and then renderInContext of that snapshot?

Comment: No, you cannot renderInContext a snapshot

Comment: Just came across this issue as well, I think the only way would be to grab a still from the AVAsset at the appropriate time...

Comment: did you every find a solution to this problem?

Comment: also stuck by this problem... ( https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video/issues/95 )

Comment: @vodkhang - Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: any solution? use use GLKView render video?

Comment: Use OpenGL render video work well

Answer (score 10):

I know you don't want to use the AVAssetImageGenerator but I've also researched this extensively and I believe the only solution currently is using the AVAssetImageGenerator. It's not that difficult as you say to get the right coordinate because you should be able to get the current time of your player. In my App the following code works perfectly:

```
-(UIImage *)getAVPlayerScreenshot 
{
    AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)self.playerItem.asset;
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
    CGImageRef thumb = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:self.playerItem.currentTime
                                              actualTime:NULL
                                                   error:NULL];
    UIImage *videoImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumb];
    CGImageRelease(thumb);
    return videoImage;
}
```

Comment: The OP specified explicitly that they didn't want to use an AVAssetImageGenerator.

Comment: @JAL yes but it's simply the only way right now and I gave a solution for the reason he didn't want to use it. So I believe this is still the best answer possible.

Comment: @JAL the OP can specify what they want and sometimes the answer is you can't. you have to do it the way you don't want. Or these are the benefits of doing it this way. Regardless of the OP not enjoying, others can benefit from the answer

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayer rending videos using GPU, so you cannot capture it using core graphics methods.

However that’s possible to capture images with `AVAssetImageGenerator`, you need specify a CMTime.

---

Update:

Forget to take a screenshot of the entire screen. `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` is my final choice, it supports video steam.

Here is my full implementation: https://github.com/BB9z/ZFPlayer/commit/a32c7244f630e69643336b65351463e00e712c7f#diff-2d23591c151edd3536066df7c18e59deR448

Comment: The OP specified explicitly that they didn't want to use an AVAssetImageGenerator.

Comment: Is there any documented mentions about why CoreGraphics doesn't work with AVPlayer?

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Works like a charm all other solutions are not working for real device, especially when its streaming...

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of Bob's answer below. I'm using AVQueuePlayer but should work for regular AVPlayer too.

```
public func getImageSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
    guard let asset = player.currentItem?.asset else { return nil }
    
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset);
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTime.zero;
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTime.zero;
    
    do {
        let thumb = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: player.currentTime(), actualTime: nil);
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: thumb);
        return image;
    } catch {
        print("⛔️ Failed to get video snapshot: \(error)");
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for taking a screenshot of you entire screen, including the AVPlayer. You only need to add a UIImageView on top of your videoplayer, which stays hidden until we take the screenshot and then we hide it again.

```
func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage? {
    //1 Hide all UI you do not want on the screenshot
    self.hideButtonsForScreenshot()

    //2 Create an screenshot from your AVPlayer
    if let url = (self.overlayPlayer?.currentItem?.asset as? AVURLAsset)?.url {

          let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

          let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
          imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTime.zero
          imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTime.zero

        if let thumb: CGImage = try? imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: self.overlayPlayer!.currentTime(), actualTime: nil) {
            let videoImage = UIImage(cgImage: thumb)
            //Note: create an image view on top of you videoPlayer in the exact dimensions, and display it before taking the screenshot
            // mine is created in the storyboard
            // 3 Put the image from the screenshot in your screenshotPhotoView and unhide it
            self.screenshotPhotoView.image = videoImage
            self.screenshotPhotoView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    
    //4 Take the screenshot
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    //5 show all UI again that you didn't want on your screenshot
    self.showButtonsForScreenshot()
    //6 Now hide the screenshotPhotoView again
    self.screenshotPhotoView.isHidden = true
    self.screenshotPhotoView.image = nil
    return image
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to take screenshot of current screen just call following method on any action event which give you Image object.

```
-(UIImage *) screenshot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //now we will position the image, X/Y away from top left corner to get the portion we want
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage.size);
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //To write image on divice.
    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage,nil, nil, nil);

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is almost identical to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23675253/2415822), and `renderInContext` will not work with `AVPlayer`.

Comment: - (UIImage*)imageFromVideoAtPath:(NSString *)path atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time {
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:time timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    [moviePlayer stop];
    return thumbnail;
}

try this.

Answer (score -5):

```
CGRect grabRect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,568);// size you want to take screenshot of. 

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
 } else {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(grabRect.size);
}
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: no, that will not do it. AVPlayer will not work with renderInContext