# iOS Fullscreen capture of WKWebview with embedded Youtube video

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, screenshot, wkwebview

I've been looking for a long time around, i found some hints but i cannot figure out how to apply this to my problem. Would appreciate any help.

What trying to achieve is pretty straight forward:

> My app includes a WKWebview playing a youtube video (with some
>   overlaying text). I added a link to take a screenshot of the screen
>   and to save it to the camera roll.

Result:

**It works perfectly in Simulator but on device I can only see as a result overlaying text and background (supposed to be the video) is black.**

Here is my current code (SWIFT 3):

```
...
// Save screenshot
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(captureScreen(), nil, nil, nil)
...

func captureScreen() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView!.bounds.size, webView!.isOpaque, 0)
    webView!.drawHierarchy(in: webView!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

I also tried (Same result)

```
...
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(captureScreen(), nil, nil, nil)
...

func captureScreen() -> UIImage {
    let image = UIApplication.shared.screenShot!
    return image
}
```

I've read online that we can't use renderInContext: because the GL layer containing the video player is not captured. So they suggest to actually merge content of UIImageView and EAGLview ([link1](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreakdevelopers/comments/2st2pl/xpost_from_rjailbreak_how_do_you_take_a/), [link2](http://getsetgames.com/2009/07/30/5-ways-to-take-screenshots-of-your-iphone-app/)).

This sounds great but most of solutions i found are written in objective-c or relatively complex ([link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352864/how-to-get-uiimage-from-eaglview), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020130/swift-how-to-take-screenshot-of-avplayerlayer), [link5](http://cladjules.blogspot.kr/2015/06/snapshot-wkwebview-in-ios.html)).

**I need help to find a solution in SWIFT.**

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: WKWebview has now a new API for ios11 supporting natively screenshot of webview, but result is actually same https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82368