# Extracting bitmap from AVPlayer is very uncertain

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, avplayer

I want to extract a `UIIMage` from a video player at a certain time point and do some processing on that image.

I have this code:

```
pausePlayer()
let time = player!.currentTime() 
imageFromVideo(url: fileURL(for: movieName!), at: time.seconds) { image in
let result = self.detectLines(image: image!    
if let result = result {
    // Display results by handing off to the InferenceViewController.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.drawNewResults(result: result)
    }
}
```

and

```
public func imageFromVideo(url: URL, at time: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

        let assetIG = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGenerator.ApertureMode.encodedPixels
        let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(30.0))
        var newTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(30.0))
        let thumbnailImageRef: CGImage

        do {
            thumbnailImageRef = try assetIG.copyCGImage(at: cmTime, actualTime: &newTime)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return completion(nil)
        }
        print("Time on click: %f", cmTime.seconds)
        print("Actual time: %f",  newTime.seconds)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImageRef))
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is a huge gap between the time I want the image and the image I get. Typically it is something like 0.2s and 0.4s, roughly an offset between 7 14 frames. So the processing I do and show is just wrong since I am not working on the image that is observed.

Example:

```
Time on click: %f 0.8333333333333334
Actual time: %f 1.0666666666666667

Time on click: %f 1.6333333333333333
Actual time: %f 2.1666666666666665
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested here: [swift: How to take screenshot of AVPlayerLayer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020130/swift-how-to-take-screenshot-of-avplayerlayer)

```
assetIG.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTime.zero
assetIG.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTime.zero
```

did the trick.