# Extracting image from AVPlayerVideo

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avplayer

I have an application where a button is pressed, the player is paused and then I want to extract the image that is shown on screen. That is to do some processing and display that result.

This was my first attempt: [Extracting bitmap from AVPlayer is very uncertain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748539/extracting-bitmap-from-avplayer-is-very-uncertain)

There is some problem there, I can't get the correct image back at the moment. So I thought maybe a different approach would be to create a bitmap using the view that contain the video.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import TensorFlowLite

class VideoPlayerController : UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rewindButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playSlowButton: UIButton!
    
    var playbackSlider: UISlider?
    var videoDuration: CMTime?
    var videoDurationSeconds: Float64?
    var movieName: String?
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var isPlaying = false
    var lines = [UIView]()
    var playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController?
    let delta = 0.02
    let slowRate: Float = 0.03
    var currentRate: Float = 1.0
    var times = [NSValue]()
    var timeObserverToken: Any?
    
    func setTimeObserverToken() {
        timeObserverToken = player!.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: times, queue: .main) {
            let time = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime())
            self.updateSlider(time: Float(time))
        }
    }
    
    func addBoundaryTimeObserver() {
        // Divide the asset's duration into quarters.
        let interval = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(videoDuration!, multiplier: 0.0001)
        var currentTime = CMTime.zero

        // Calculate boundary times
        while currentTime < videoDuration! {
            currentTime = currentTime + interval
            times.append(NSValue(time:currentTime))
        }
        setTimeObserverToken()
    }
    
    func updateSlider(time: Float) {
        playbackSlider?.setValue(time, animated: true)
    }

    func removeBoundaryTimeObserver() {
        if let timeObserverToken = timeObserverToken {
            player!.removeTimeObserver(timeObserverToken)
            self.timeObserverToken = nil
        }
    }

    func setupPlayer(movieName: String) {
        let movieUrl = fileURL(for: movieName)
        player = AVPlayer(url: movieUrl)
        let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoPlayerView.frame.width, height: videoPlayerView.frame.height)
        playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController!.player = player
        playerViewController?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        playerViewController!.view.frame = playerFrame
        playerViewController!.showsPlaybackControls = false
        addChild(playerViewController!)
        videoPlayerView.addSubview(playerViewController!.view)
        playerViewController!.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    func setupPlaybackSlider() {
        let sliderWidth = 300
        let sliderHeight = 20
        let sliderX = Int((self.view.frame.width - CGFloat(sliderWidth)) / 2.0)
        let sliderY = Int(self.view.frame.height - 2.5 * self.playButton.frame.height)
        playbackSlider = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x:sliderX, y: sliderY, width:sliderWidth, height:sliderHeight))
        playbackSlider!.minimumValue = 0
        
        videoDuration = (player!.currentItem?.asset.duration)!
        videoDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration!)
        
        playbackSlider!.maximumValue = Float(videoDurationSeconds!)
        playbackSlider!.isContinuous = true
        playbackSlider!.tintColor = UIColor.green
        
        playbackSlider!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playbackSliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        self.view.addSubview(playbackSlider!)
        addBoundaryTimeObserver()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let movieName = movieName {
            setupPlayer(movieName: movieName)
            setupPlaybackSlider();
        }
        
        let rewindText = "- \(delta) s"
        let forwardText = "+ \(delta) s"

        rewindButton.setTitle(rewindText, for: .normal)
        forwardButton.setTitle(forwardText, for: .normal)
    }
    
    @objc func playbackSliderValueChanged(_ playbackSlider:UISlider)
    {
        if (isPlaying) {
            pausePlayer()
        }
        let seconds : Int64 = Int64(playbackSlider.value)
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
        player!.seek(to: targetTime)
    }
    
    func getNewLineViews(lines: [LineSegment], color: UIColor) -> [UIView] {
        let widthScale = videoPlayerView.frame.width / CGFloat(inputWidth)
        let heightScale = videoPlayerView.frame.height / CGFloat(inputHeight)
        var lineViews = [UIView]()
        
        for line in lines {
            let view = UIView()
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let start = CGPoint(x: Double(widthScale) * line.start.x,
                                y: Double(heightScale) * line.start.y)
            let end = CGPoint(x: Double(widthScale) * line.end.x,
                              y: Double(heightScale) * line.end.y)
            path.move(to: start)
            path.addLine(to: end)
            
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
            view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            lineViews.append(view)
        }
        return lineViews
    }
    
    func getLines(lines: [LineSegment]) {
        let widthScale = videoPlayerView.frame.width / CGFloat(inputWidth)
        let heightScale = videoPlayerView.frame.height / CGFloat(inputHeight)
         
        for line in lines {
            let view = UIView()
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let start = CGPoint(x: Double(widthScale) * line.start.x,
                                y: Double(heightScale) * line.start.y)
            let end = CGPoint(x: Double(widthScale) * line.end.x,
                              y: Double(heightScale) * line.end.y)
            path.move(to: start)
            path.addLine(to: end)
            
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
            view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            self.lines.append(view)
        }
    }
    
    func getValidRectangles(rectangles: [LineSegment?]) -> [LineSegment] {
        var result = [LineSegment]()
        for rectangle in rectangles {
            if let rectangle = rectangle {
                result.append(rectangle)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    
    
    func drawNewResults(result: Result) {
        for view in self.lines {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        let lines = getValidRectangles(rectangles: result.inferences)
        self.lines = getNewLineViews(lines: lines, color: UIColor.red)
        for lineView in self.lines {
            videoPlayerView!.addSubview(lineView)
        }
    }
    
    func pausePlayer() {
        player?.pause()
        playButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        isPlaying = false
    }
    
    func startPlayer() {
        setTimeObserverToken()
        player!.play()
        player!.rate = currentRate
        playButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        isPlaying = true
    }
    
    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
        if (!isPlaying) {
            startPlayer()
        } else {
            pausePlayer()
        }
        let currentTime = player!.currentTime()
        updateSlider(time: Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime)))
    }
    
    @IBAction func playSlow(_ sender: Any) {
        if (currentRate > 0.99) {
            currentRate = slowRate
            playSlowButton.setTitle("Normal", for: .normal)
        } else {
            currentRate = 1.0
            playSlowButton.setTitle("Slow", for: .normal)
        }
        if (isPlaying) {
            player!.rate = currentRate
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func rewindPlayer(_ sender: Any) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            pausePlayer()
        }
        let currentTime = player!.currentTime()
        let zeroTime = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: currentTime.timescale)
        let deltaTime =  CMTime(seconds: delta, preferredTimescale: currentTime.timescale)
        let seekTime = max(zeroTime, (currentTime - deltaTime))
        player!.seek(to: seekTime, toleranceBefore: deltaTime, toleranceAfter: zeroTime)
        updateSlider(time: Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(seekTime)))
    }
    
    @IBAction func forwardPlayer(_ sender: Any) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            pausePlayer()
        }
        let currentTime = player!.currentTime()
        let endTime = player!.currentItem?.duration
        let deltaTime =  CMTime(seconds: delta, preferredTimescale: currentTime.timescale)
        let seekTime = min(endTime!, (currentTime + deltaTime))
        let zeroTime = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: currentTime.timescale)
        player!.seek(to: seekTime, toleranceBefore: zeroTime, toleranceAfter: deltaTime)
        updateSlider(time: Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(seekTime)))
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        removeBoundaryTimeObserver()
    }
        
    @IBAction func analyzeImage(_ sender: Any) {
        pausePlayer()
        let time = player!.currentTime()
        imageFromVideo(url: fileURL(for: movieName!), at: time.seconds) { image in
            let result = self.detectLines(image: image!)
            if let result = result {
                // Display results by handing off to the InferenceViewController.
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.drawNewResults(result: result)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func detectLines(image: UIImage) -> Result?{
        let newImage = videoPlayerView!.asImage()
        let outputTensor: Tensor
        guard let rgbData = newImage.scaledData(
            with: CGSize(width: inputWidth, height: inputHeight),
            byteCount: inputWidth * inputHeight * inputChannels
                * batchSize,
            isQuantized: false
        )
        else {
            print("Failed to convert the image buffer to RGB data.")
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let interpreter = getInterpreter()!
            try interpreter.copy(rgbData, toInputAt: 0)
            
            try interpreter.invoke()
            outputTensor = try interpreter.output(at: 0)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to invoke the interpreter with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
        
        let outputArray = outputTensor.data.toArray(type: Float32.self)
        return extractLinesFromPoints(output: outputArray, outputShape: outputTensor.shape.dimensions)
    }
    
    func getInterpreter() -> Interpreter? {
        var interpreter: Interpreter
        let modelFilename = MobileNet.modelInfo.name
        guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.path(
            forResource: modelFilename,
            ofType: MobileNet.modelInfo.extension
        ) else {
            print("Failed to load the model with name: \(modelFilename).")
            return nil
        }
        let options = Interpreter.Options()
        do {
            interpreter = try Interpreter(modelPath: modelPath, options: options)
            try interpreter.allocateTensors()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create the interpreter with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
        return interpreter
    }
}

extension UIView {

    // Using a function since `var image` might conflict with an existing variable
    // (like on `UIImageView`)
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
            self.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return UIImage(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried this and some other things, but all I get is a black image.

Comment: What does a guy named 'videoPlayerView' come from?

Comment: The view that contains the video I am playing. Created in storyboard, weak reference.

Comment: `didMove`?  Under what class are you writing code?