# Swift: Why my screenshot not displaying Avplayer video?

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

In my project i used AVPlayerViewController in an embedded view.And allow user to draw on the video.To take a screenshot i used the below code...

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0);
            self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

The problem is when i run the above code in simulator it works well but in Physical device it returns black image

Any suggestion would be helpful

[image: Simulator screenshot]

iPad screenshot:
[image: ipad screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Please see the 2nd answer in this link 
[Screenshot for AVPlayer and Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286252/screenshot-for-a%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bvplayer-and-video)

Comment: Even after changing to false/1.0 it returns black screen in iPad but it works well in simulator

Comment: Please see the 2nd answer in this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286252/screenshot-for-avplayer-and-video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286252/screenshot-for-avplayer-and-video)

Comment: It captures the video alone not the UIView.I need both UiView and Video @ Pranav Pravakar