# Why I can only take a screenshot with AVAssetImageGenerator for AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm currently running into an issue where I need to take a screenshot of `UIView` which has a `AVPlayerLayer` attached to it.

I read some [Apple's documents for AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH7-SW5), and it suggests to use `AVAssetImageGenerator`. However, I don't have access to `AVPlayer` object.

I tried some solutions like

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(videoPlayerView.bounds.size, videoPlayerView.isOpaque, 0)
videoPlayerView.drawHierarchy(in: videoPlayerView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

and

```
videoPlayerView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

and

```
videoPlayerView.layer.render(in: context)
```

but none of them work.

I also came across this [Screenshot for AVPlayer and Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286252/screenshot-for-avplayer-and-video), it seems like the current only solution is using `AVAssetImageGenerator`.

Can anyone help me to understand why?

Comment: you want a snapshot of UIView(with its subviews), which can be achieved by using **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions**. but AVPlayerlayer as a subview, it's not possible. On the other hand, using **AVAssetImageGenerator**, you can easily get a **thumbimage** from a video file in a specific time (you must have access to AVAsset). Please clarify why you don't have access to AVPlayer object